# extracting objects in a HashSet and Generate columns with object Name variable as the column title

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, devexpress, hashset

Hello am New to Winform and would like an assistance in generating Columns in a datagrid that is editable. I have a Exam Result Model that has a Studentadmin,Collection of subjects Object and Score.In that I want the user to Input score of each Subjects in a datagrid that the columns are generated depending on the No of subjects the Student Takes.
**Student Class.**

```
public class Student
{
   public int StudentId { get; set; }
   public string Fname { get; set; }
   public string AdminNo { get; set; }
   public int? ClassId { get; set; }
   public Class Calass { get;set }

}
```

**ExamResult Class.**

```
public class ExamResult
{
    public int ExamScoreId { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

**Class class.**

```
public class Class
{
   public int ClassId { get; set; }
   public  string Clssname { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }

   public Class()
   {
       Subjects = new HashSet<Subject>();
    }
}
```

A different class can have different no of subjects.Kindly help

Comment: You need to do proper code formatting in your post and actually have some code showing your attempt

Comment: I have done that

Comment: Why not a row for each subject?

Comment: Because Each row will have a record for each student in that lets say row 2 can have student with admin 123  and marks score for subject 1 to subject 13

Comment: wouldn't it make sense to have one student at a time in the grid? There's a reason you have had to ask this question, it is unorthodox design.

Comment: what am trying to achieve is  like that  of a spreadsheet where the list of on the Column of student admin, the rows generated equal to the number of student in that class hence the exam officer inputs subjects marks compiled and is update in the database as a batch not as a single entity

Comment: So, you will have subject columns on each student even if the student did not participate in that subject? Won't that create data entry confusion and errors? I'm sorry to argue, but if I understand correctly, it seems wrong. Otherwise, it is not so hard to create a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/creating-a-datatable) (as one example of a datasource) and DataColumns by looping over your list of subjects then bind the grid to the datatable.

Comment: No real code here is what I am saying, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model

Comment: You cannot get these columns auto-generated, but you can add them manually as [unbound columns](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1477/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Views/Grid-View/Unbound-Columns) and then retrieve data for these columns from the hash set inside the CustomUnboundColumnData event handler. I do not have enough time to make a complete answer, sorry. I hope that this hint will be helpful.

Comment: Actually that has been my query since an am glad for that hint. Here I have two Hash sets, Student and an subjects where I would want for Each set of student I Enter all subjects per exam than filling one subject at a Time.Hence Saving the amount of time needed to enter the data.My view Has to populated the student Hash set depending on the the class. The other options was to achieve Student Set with Two columns, the Admission column and subject Column that will store the Subject Score from user and bulk insert in the database